# Convert e.NewValue to decimal

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I'm trying handle value changing so I can make calculation

```
    private void supplierDiscountPercetangeSpinEdit_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal price, percentage, calculatedPrice;

        price = (decimal)supplierPriceSpinEdit.EditValue;
        percentage = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValue);  // breakpoint 1
        calculatedPrice = Popust.Izracunaj(price, percentage); // breakpoint 2

        supplierPriceWithDiscountSpinEdit.EditValue = calculatedPrice;
    }
```

At Breakpoint 1 `e.NewValue` is `object {string} "1.00"`

At Breakpoint 2 `percentage` is `object {decimal} 100`

and it has to be `1.00M`

How can i convert `e.NewValue` to decimal?

Comment: Already tried to parse but it just ignores decimal mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `CultureInfo`: in your current culture *'.'* is a **thousand** separator, not a **decimal** one; that's why

```
  1.00 -> 100 // <- thousand separator '.' removed
```

Try put it like

```
  Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```